# Angular 2 app.module is growing by the day. What can I do about it?

Tags: angular

Why am I beginning to feel like my app.module has just become a global registry?

I'm developing a medium sized web app and already I have well over 30 declarations and imports (and counting fast).

What is the best pattern for breaking the app.module up into more manageable modules?

Comment: Break it to feature modules and import in those modules the relevant components. Say you have a dashboard with a menu, each menu item can be a feature module that handles its purpose (children). This way you will almost have no declarations in the root module.